# Social login system for Play 2 framework

Tags: playframework-2.0

I am newbie to Play 2 framework. I came across to SECURESOCIAL login system, but on it's github site, it is mentioned that it currently doesn't support YAHOO and LINKEDIN. Can some one guide me better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take a look at this other module: [play-authenticate](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate)

But you'll have to write your own [providers](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate/tree/master/code/app/com/feth/play/module/pa/providers) for Yahoo and LinkedIn.

Yahoo uses a OpenID 2.0 method, a doc can be found [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide).

LinkedIn uses a Oauth 1.0a method (such as [Twitter](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate/blob/master/code/app/com/feth/play/module/pa/providers/oauth1/twitter/TwitterAuthProvider.java)), a doc can be found [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication).

Answer (score 2):

I've created what you're looking for : a Play 2.x client in Scala and Java which supports OAuth/CAS/OpenID/HTTP authentication and user profile retrieval : https://github.com/pac4j/play-pac4j.

For OAuth support, it's based on Scribe and supports **Yahoo, LinkedIn**, Facebook, Twitter, Google, DropBox, Github, Windows live, WordPress...